# How to apply a changes on all the tables on a page except a few (using jquery)?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to apply changes to all the tables on a page except few of them.

I tried doing this but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
 $("table:not(#tblHdrContent) tr").find("td:eq(1)").css("text-align", "right");
```

Comment: To troubleshoot this, start be putting `$("table:not(#tblHdrContent) tr")` in the javascript console and see if it returns elements

Comment: If it works then add the .find, etc. that way you can determine where the point of failure is.

Comment: By a few tables, you are insinuating those few tables all have the same ID, and that wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be in your .find() call. Try this:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fZuN/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table:not(#tblHdrContent) tr td:eq(1)").css("text-align", "right");
});
```

EDIT: Also just a side note in the fiddle i used eq(0) since i only wrote one td in. Just a reminder that :eq works off of a 0-based index.

-Ken

Answer (score 3):

this should do it:

```
$("table").not('#tblHdrContent').find("td:eq(1)").css("text-align", "right");
```

Comment: Should .find be `.find("td:eq(1) tr")` since it looks like he wants to apply the style to tr's?

Comment: not,,the final find is on first TD, it does not matter with TR